# regular expression matching perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match part of a string to a yes or no answer.  The string goes either: `'{"valid_js":"yes"...'` or `'{"valid_js":"no"...'`.   I'm trying to get the "yes" or "no"

Can I just use something like:

```
/:."yes"/g
```

Or do I need something more complicated?

Comment: This looks like [JSON](http://enwp.org/JSON). Is there any reason against using a [JSON parser](http://p3rl.org/JSON)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
if (m/"valid_js":"(yes|no)"/)
{
    # At this point $1 will contain either yes or no
    if ($1 eq 'yes')
    {
      # Answer is yes
    }
    else
    {
      # Answer is no
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Code Monkey.  I actually figured that out last night while trying various regex.  As a newbie I still try and look for a complicated answer when there is a simple solution.

Comment: do you know of any good tutorials on regex's?? I'm reading Perl Programming the O'Reilly book right now but perhaps there's better material out there.

Comment: I find that O'Reilly books are usually pretty good. There are very useful web sites that allow you to test your regular expressions, such as http://regexpal.com.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic form of regexp:

```
valid_js["]:["](yes|no)["] -> $1
```

You can use that regexp to match or replace.

Comment: do i need to put it in between the //?

Comment: why are double quotes in a character class? it has no meaning in regex

Comment: The quotes must be preceded by backslash, or inserted in [].

Comment: I wrote you just the regexp, without a specific call. You will insert this regexp inside a function call. I do not know what you want to do.

Comment: I cannot help you more. I use perl just in the `rename` command of linux, where I make `sed` calls to replace strings... The expression I provided you is correct -- it you can help of it to do what you need it is ok -- I cannot help more.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
$input = '{"valid_js":"yes"...';

if (($input =~ m/"valid_js":"(.*?)"/) && ($1 eq 'yes')) {
  print "1: yes\n";
}

$input = '{"valid_js":"no"...';

if (($input =~ m/"valid_js":"(.*?)"/) && ($1 eq 'yes')) {
  print "2: yes\n";
}
```

You can test the code [here](http://ideone.com/DXG5F).